# How to prove that the given encryption scheme have ciphertext indistinguishability for all PPT adversaries?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator, quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

[image]

I am not sure how to prove that the given two scheme is perfectly indistinguishable for all PPT adversaries!

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. The usual way is assuming that they are not, then show that Enc cannot have Ind.

Comment: Ok so if i assume they are not PPT then what should be my next step?